# Check if user is on list

Tags: c#, arrays, json, contains, exists

I have Array in JSON file. File looks like this:

```
["Maverick", "rick", "Rick", "prick", "rick_07"]
```

I have a username. I want to check if this username is in Array.

```
public string UserToCheck = "rick";
```

So im reading json file from URL...

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var json = webClient.DownloadString("http://example.ex/users.json");
    // Here I want to check if user is on list
    }
}
```

But how Can I check if "UserToCheck" exactly match one of users from array?

Comment: do a simple google search on Parsing a JSON File or do this for example in a google search `C# stackoverflow how to check for a string inside json array`

Comment: Do I need to parse this file?

Comment: If you really have that little data, just use String.Contains. However, if you have more, parsing is probably going to offer better performance.

Comment: no..using `.Contains()` would not work in this case please leave this page for like 2 seconds and do a simple google search on C# parsing Json . come on...

Comment: @LuisTeijon the question you've suggested is not C# at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse your Json with the great [Newtonsoft Json Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);    
users.Contains(UserToCheck);
```

As this is case sensitive, you could use LINQ: `users.Any(u => String.Equals(u, UserToCheck, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: Your code is exactly what I needed. Works perfect! Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Trying parsing the object using JSON parsing. This requires placing the JSON string object into `JSON.Parse` method.

This portion may be missing:

```
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(jObj);
```

Helpful links: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm
http://masnun.com/2011/07/08/quick-json-parsing-with-c-sharp.html

To check the string for names, break the names up into a list with C# and iterate through that to check the results.